# How to find the nearest pair of parallel planes containing a given set of 3-dimensional points

Tags: geometry

There is a finite set of points in the 3-dimensional space.

I am seeking to contain them between two parallel planes, such that all points are located between the planes with a condition that the distance between planes is minimal.

In other words, I am seeking to find a 3-dimensional vector of unit length such that orthogonal projections of all points onto this vector have minimal spread along it.

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to compute such vector.

Comment: Is the set finite?

Comment: The set is finite.

Comment: An optimal vector will either be perpendicular to a face or to two separate edges of the convex hull of your point set, so only finitely many vectors need to be tried ...